# How do I make my motors speed change?

Tags: adafruit, arduino-motor-shield

I'm using an Adafruit V1 Motor Shield for coding two 12 volt DC motors. In my code I'm changing the set speed, but the motors still seem to be going the same speed, which is really fast, and I want them to go slow.  What do I change to make my motors speed run the way I want them to run?

Here's my code below:

```cpp
#include <AFMotor.h>

AF_DCMotor motor1(1);
AF_DCMotor motor2(2);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
  Serial.println("Motor test!");
  // turn on motor
  motor1.setSpeed(3);
  motor2.setSpeed(5);
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t i;

  //second motor
  Serial.print("tick");

  motor2.run(FORWARD);

  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }

  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  Serial.print("tick");
  
  motor2.run(FORWARD);

  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }

  Serial.print("tick");
  
  motor2.run(FORWARD);

  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }

  Serial.print("tick");
  
  motor2.run(FORWARD);

  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }

  Serial.print("tick");
  
  motor2.run(FORWARD);

  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }

  //1 motor
  Serial.print("tick");
  
  motor1.run(FORWARD);

  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor1.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor1.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }

  Serial.print("tick");
  
  motor2.run(FORWARD);

  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  Serial.print("tick");
  
  motor2.run(FORWARD);

  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor2.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  Serial.print("tack");
  
  motor1.run(BACKWARD);

  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor1.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
 
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor1.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: delete all of the code inside `loop()` ... what happens then?

Comment: `What do I change to make my motors speed run the way I want them to run?` ... how is anyone supposed to guess how you want the motors to run?

Comment: @jsotola  I mean by like how do i change the speed?

Comment: please read my first comment

Comment: @jsotola when I delete all of the code inside void loop(), nothing happens.

Comment: please add `motor1.run(FORWARD);`

Comment: @jsotola Its still the same speed. I have the power supply of 12v hooked up to the Arduino mega, which makes the motor sheild turn on, but is there any chance that it could be that there is to much power going to the motor shield which is causing the motors to spin faster?

Comment: are you saying that you are connecting 12 V to something that is not rated for such a voltage?

Comment: The arduino mega is 12 volts but the motor shield is 5 volts

Comment: hey . so if you have multimeter take it and check for the voltage at the terminals for the motor and the voltage should change according to the speed you have set

Comment: It looks like that motor shield can control stepper motors, servos, or variable speed DC motors. Are you using variable speed DC motors? (What model of motors are you using?)